# How to attach a tail to draggable element using jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a draggable element which will have a tail on its left side. When I will be dragging it on the right side the associated tail should dynamically expand making sure it is attached to the dragged element.

Here is the sample which I was trying:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        containment: $('this').closest('#container'),
        cursor: '-moz-grabbing'
    });
});
```

```css
#container{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#draggable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    border:0.2px solid black;
}
#draggableTail {
  height:0.1px;
  width:100px;
  margin-top:40px;
  border:2px solid black;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
<div id='draggableTail'>
</div>
<div id="draggable">
<div id="someContent">
<p>
HAVE A GOOD DAY
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have also create a jsfiddle for the same - http://jsfiddle.net/w8fhutx8/2/

Comment: This is the closest i can do right now http://jsfiddle.net/w8fhutx8/4/

Comment: Thanks @CarstenLøvboAndersen but this is not something I am looking for.

Comment: I've miss read your question, is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/w8fhutx8/5/?

Comment: Thanks. Awesome. This is what I was looking for.